# Finish all called Intents

Tags: java, android

I got two activities, one active and other paused and I want to close/finish all the two activities and start another intent. I tried this inside the active activity:

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Init.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

then I tried to close the program inside Init class and it appeared me the previous paused activity. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: **"I got two intents, one active and other paused..."** - You mean you have two Activities I presume? An `Intent` is NOT an `Activity`.

Comment: Yes, with Intents I mean Activities

Comment: @user1491548 Please update the original post with corrections as required. (There should be an "edit" button under the tags.)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling not calling `finish()` before you launch the newest intent and use these flags

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Init.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried this:
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Init.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

Comment: try FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME instead of CLEAR_TOP

Comment: better yet FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Comment: Strange, I don't have this functions in my library

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME and CLEAR_TASK were added at API level 11 - not the best of ideas for backwards compatibility reasons but really your best option here, may be why you can't see it

Comment: But I have API 11 installed. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: Not in a way that I would recommend

Comment: @user1491548: You may have it installed but is it, or higher than API 11, being used in your Project?